# My innerHTML is coming out to be null despite using id or class or querySelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml

This is the most frequent problem I come across, in this file was trying to access the innerHTML of the textarea using the same property.

But the error says that the input.innerHTML is null.

You can understand better by code,

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Body.css';
import axios from "axios";
import './Body.css'
export default function Navbar() {
    let noteArray;
    let input =  document.getElementById('.input_area') ;
    const AddNote = () =>{
        console.log("here" ,input.innerHTML) ; 
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div className="input_info">
                    <textarea id='input_area' name=""  cols="50" rows="5">op</textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button onClick={AddNote} className='add'>Add Note</button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id='display_info' >
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I tried from class, id, and querySelector but none of them is working.

Can anyone suggest me some edits?

EDIT--

[image: THIS IS THE CONSOLE]

Comment: Are you sure that by the time you access innerHTML the desired element is already in the DOM?

Comment: innerHTML  and value both are not working

Comment: Please see I have updated the code, I removed the onClick by mistake earlier.

Comment: why do you use dom functions? it is a react anti-pattern. If you are trying to change your textarea use states

Comment: @traktor you are wrong

Comment: You should learn about [reacts virtual dom](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html). Then you should familiarise yourself with hooks, especially the [useRef hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure that the elements of the component has been mounted to the `DOM` you need to execute the selection queries in `useEffect` hook, Also you need to use `value` attribute instead of `innerHTML`

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './Body.css';
import axios from "axios";
import './Body.css'
export default function Navbar() {
    let noteArray;
    useEffect(() => {
       let input =  document.getElementById('.input_area');
       console.log("here" ,input.value);
    })
    
    const AddNote = () =>{
       let input =  document.getElementById('.input_area');
       console.log("here" ,input.value); 
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div className="input_info">
                    <textarea id='input_area' name=""  cols="50" rows="5">op</textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button onClick={AddNote} className='add'>Add Note</button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id='display_info' >
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

But, I suggest you use `useRef` instead of `DOM` select queries.

For example

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import './Body.css';
import axios from "axios";
import './Body.css'
export default function Navbar() {
    let noteArray;
    const textAreaRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(textAreaRef.current.value)
    })
    
    const AddNote = () =>{
       console.log(textAreaRef.current.value)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div className="input_info">
                    <textarea ref={textAreaRef} id='input_area' name=""  cols="50" rows="5">op</textarea>
                    <br />
                    <button onClick={AddNote} className='add'>Add Note</button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id='display_info' >
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: When there is not `op` then I am giving input to the textarea on the webpage and on clicking add to note there is nothing in the console and the pointer moves to the next line. I am using the second method. Moreover the first methods still shows innerHTML is null.

Comment: @Ankit What do you mean by `op`, and which pointer moves to the next line?

Comment: `op` is initially in innerHTML of textarea you can see in the code. When I am clicking the add note button then in console nothing is showing and it moves to the next line in the console, as if something is being printed there but nothing is actually showing up.

Comment: I have pasted the console image in the question, I pressed add button 6 times.

Comment: @Ankit, If you need to get the value of the `textarea` after input inside it you need to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: @Ankit, I just update the answer, check again.

Comment: You can do the same so that I can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Navbar() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("op");
    const [noteArray, setNoteArray] = useState([])
    const addNote = () => {
        setNoteArray((prevState) => ([...prevState, input]))
    }

    const inputChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="input_info">
                <textarea id='input_area' name="" cols="50" rows="5" value={input} onChange={e => inputChange(e)}></textarea>
                <br />
                <button className='add' onClick={addNote}>Add Note</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id='display_info' >
                <ul>
                    {noteArray.map(val => {
                        return <li>{val}</li>
                    })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<body id="root"></body>
```

I guess this is what you want to achieve and a better pattern in react. Also you can improve it by changing the data structure of note array